# Запрет на выполнение действий после цикла до полного завершения цикла

Tags: java, циклы

У меня есть код. Он проверяет наличие в инвентаре игрока разных предметов.

```
public void detectdrop(Player p, int i, int[] c, Material[] mat) {
    int am = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> amm = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int d = 0;
    while(d < mat.length) {
        for(int iii = 0; iii < 36; iii++) {
            if(p.getInventory().getItem(iii) != null) {
                if(p.getInventory().getItem(iii).getType() == mat[d]) {
                    am += p.getInventory().getItem(iii).getAmount();
                }
            }
        }
        amm.add(am);
        d++;
    }
    int o = 0;
    while(o < amm.size()) {
        if(amm.get(o) < c[o]) {
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Не хватает ресурсов.");
            return;
        }
        o++;
    }
    p.sendMessage("irc=" + amm.get(0));
    p.sendMessage("golc=" + amm.get(1));
    in.set(i, in.get(i) + 1);
    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Улучшение успешно!");
    drop(p, c, mat);
    p.closeInventory();
}
```

Как только не пытался менять код, всё бестолку. Если у игрока есть только первый предмет из массива, происходит улучшение. Я уже просто ну не знаю, что сделать! Вожусь с этим второй день... Думаю как-то запретить выполнение действий, которые находятся после цикла, ДО ПОЛНОГО завершения цикла. А возможно, проблема в другом, но в чём? И разве пока цикл не завершит свою работу, следующий код будет работать?
P.S. Это код использует Bukkit API. И на всякий случай, вот один из примеров, как я этот метод вызываю:
`Material[] mat = {Material.IRON_INGOT, Material.GOLD_INGOT};
int[] c = {64,32};
detectdrop(p,ii,c,mat);`
где c - количества предметов, а mat - материал (сам предмет).

Comment: Ваш код дурно пахнет, много неочевидных переменных, таких как  am, amm, i, c, так же у вас присутствует дублирование обращений, например: p.getInventory().getItem(iii), от этого сложно понять суть того, что делает код и в чем именно проблема. В вопросе есть предложение: "Если у игрока есть только первый предмет из массива, происходит улучшение." это некорректное поведение? Какого поведения вы хотите добиться от кода? Попробуйте представить код, чтоб мы могли его выполнить у себя и увидеть некорректное поведение.

Comment: Это часть кода из самописного плагина для сервера minecraft (Bukkit API). Массив "mat" - предметы, которые проверяются в инвентаре. (К примеру, железо и золото). А массив "c" - количества этих предметов. Проблема заключается в том, что на практике этот код проверяет наличие лишь первого предмета (64 железа), а золото он игнорирует. Из-за этого игроки могут просто копить железо, не тратя золото и это явно неправильно.